# How to configure filepath to valueBlobFile for liquibase insert

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

Below is change set. And data file present at /src/main/resources/db/changelog

```
<changeSet author="Krishna" id="insert-3">
    <insert tableName="blob_test">
        <column name="name" value="Name3" />
        <column name="formData" type="longblob" valueBlobFile="../../../db/changelog/dc_form_definition_202304051700.csv-1.data.txt"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

Getting exception as below thought the file is present inside resource directory.

Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: BLOB resource not found: ../../../db/changelog/dc_form_definition_202304051700.csv-1.data.txt

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem after debugging Liquibase code.

I have configured **application.property** for change log file as **spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/changelog-master.xml**.

Liquibase form the resource path as below.

Basepath derived from 'spring.liquibase.change-log'(for spring boot). As per my configuration, '**db/changelog**' is basepath and then concatenate it with configured value for valueBlobFile. So process looking for resource as '**db/changelog/../../../db/changelog/dc_form_definition_202304051700.csv-1.data.txt**' which does not exist.

I have corrected the data file path and working fine.

This I am using to load file data to bytea column.